# Connect to PostgreSQL from different host

Tags: postgresql, configuration, connectivity

I am facing error while connecting to the PostgreSQL server from different host, I configured both `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`  but unfortunately with no result.

So I have installed PostgreSQL on Debian from package, added user with `createuser` and `useradd`, then created db via `createdb` as my custom user as an owner. Afterwards I have set `postgresql.conf` with these values

```
listen_addresses = '*'
ssl = false
```

And added this line in `pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all      all     192.168.0.0/24  md5
```

Then I have restarted service and tried to connect from my machine via `psql -U admin -d admin -h 10.10.30.88`and I am getting this error

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.10.195", user "admin", database "admin", SSL off
```

So have I forgotten about something?

Whole `pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all     all     192.168.0.0/24  md5
host    all     all     10.10.0.0/24    md5
```

`ipconfig` PostgreSQL server

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:00:00:03  
      inet addr:10.10.30.88  Bcast:10.10.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe00:3/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:365126 (356.5 KiB)  TX bytes:306782 (299.5 KiB)
```

`ipconfig` from other VM in same network

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:00:00:15  
      inet addr:10.10.30.83  Bcast:10.10.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe00:15/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:144749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:18950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:16160192 (15.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1323052 (1.2 MiB)
```

`ipconfig` from my machine

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:7d:46:11:5c:ab  
      inet addr:192.168.10.195  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c67d:46ff:fe11:5cab/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:198498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:78205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:168115954 (168.1 MB)  TX bytes:10312744 (10.3 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f0600000-f0620000
```

I have my own KVM as well (not running)

```
virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:e4:de:95:07:1b  
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Wifi is not enabled

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:fd:ce:b3:dc:e7  
      inet6 addr: fe80::aefd:ceff:feb3:dce7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:32251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3268413 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:21321 (21.3 KB)
```

Comment: 192.168.10.195 - it's in the error log.

Comment: Show us the whole `pg_hba.conf` file. But you are trying to connect to `-h 10.10.30.88`. Not to a `192.168.x.x` address.

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the virtual machine which runs on the `192.168.x.x` - I can SSH to it so I thought it doesn't matter from the connection perspective.

Comment: Btw result is the same when I try to connect from `10.10.x.x` machine.

Comment: OK. What does `ifconfig` shows (in the machine where the Postgres server runs)? And what does it show on the machine you are trying to connect from (it should be `192.168.10.195` and perhaps some more)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is probably due to this line:

```
host    all     all   192.168.0.0/24  md5
```

This (the `24`) basically tells Postgres to allow connections from any machine that has IP of the form: `192.168.0.x`. So, your `192.168.10.195` does not match the criteria. You can replace it with:

```
host    all     all   192.168.0.0/16  md5     -- any 192.168.x.x
```

or

```
host    all     all   192.168.10.0/24  md5    -- any 192.168.10.x
```

or

```
host    all     all   192.168.10.195/32  md5  -- only 192.168.10.195
```

depending on what range of IPs you want to allow.

Comment: Great, that seems to work! I really don't know how could I have overlooked this :)

Comment: Did it work? You may want to try altering the `10.10.0.0./24` instead (to `10.10.0.0./16` or `10.10.30.0/24` or ..). I'm not sure you've shown the whole ifconfig outputs. Your comment says that the VM runs in 192.168.x.x but the output shows 10.10.x.x

Comment: I meant the host OS which has the KVM installed, VMs itself are in `10.10.x.x`. It works now so great :)